# NullReferenceException in BinaryTree search algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

```
public int find(int value) {
        Node curr = root;
        while (curr != null) {
            if (curr.value == value) {
                return value;//success
            }
            if (curr.value < value) {
                curr = curr.lChild;
            }
            if (curr.value > value) {
                curr = curr.rChild;
            }
            if (curr.value == null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;//No Value
    }
```

I cant see whats wrong with the configuration of this binaryTree Search

Comment: What happens in your loop if curr.value < value and curr.lChild is null ? Think about it. Also, debug your code with a debugger.

Comment: Please provide the code of your `Node` class (or at best a [mcve]) and sample input data.

Comment: change `if`s into `else if`s

Answer (score 0):

The implementation you use does not use the fact that the cases that need to be considered are mutually exclusive. If one case is hit, an assignment might take place which destroys the precondition of the following cases. Consider the following implementation which explicitly makes the cases mutually exclusive.

```
public int find(int value) {
    Node curr = root;
    while (curr != null) {
        if (curr.value == value) {
            return value;
        }
        else if (curr.value < value) {
            curr = curr.lChild;
        }
        else if (curr.value > value) {
            curr = curr.rChild;
        }
        else if (curr.value == null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not think that it matters that much, since the *conditions* are mutually exclusive. If `curr.value < value` evaluates to true, `curr.value > value` and `curr.value == null` will necessarily evaluate to `false`, unless `curr.value` is of a custom type that overrides `>`, `<` and `==`.

Comment: `else if (curr.value == null)` - can't happen. value is an `int`.

Comment: @PaulKertscher If `curr.value < value` holds, `curr` is assigned `curr.lchild`. If after the assignment `curr` is `null`, the subsequent check `curr.value == null` is dereferencing a `null` pointer; the subsequent check should have been omitted in the first place.